# webcoreapi dotnet : authentication fusionauth

Tags: .net-core, fusionauth

I am trying to securise my CoreWebApi access with FusionAuth (dotnet 6)
I started from the VisualStudio sample and added :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("FusionAuth"));

builder.Services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; });
```

And added a section in my app configuration :

```
"FusionAuth": {
  "Instance": "http://localhost:9011",
  "ClientId": "xx1",
  "ClientSecret": "xx2",
  "TenantId": "xx3",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

(xx1, xx2 and xx3 are my clientId and clientSecret from application , and tenant id of my fusionauth - i replaced here to quote)

I'm very new in dotnet and oauth, i tried to read the doc but i'm a little lost.
When i try to call an API url of my app, i receive a 401.

**EDIT :**
Ok, i understand that i need to give my token in order to execute my request (sorry i'm slow)

So i added the token in the header in my curl request

```
 curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer my_token' my_api_url
```

where my_token is the token returned by fusionauth login api (both token or refresh_token) , but now i get the error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong here ?
Thank you for any feedback

Comment: What kind of key is the token being signed by? (You can see that by going to the application configuration in FusionAuth, then the JWT tab. This will point you to a key, which you can then learn more about by going to Settings -> Key Master.)

I am pretty sure you want to use an asymmetric key (RSA).

Comment: It is set with the default values of FusionAuth, Default signing key (HS256)

Comment: I dont understand if AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi only works for connecting to an Azur identity server, or if i can use it with FusionApp too .... Maybe that's why it is not working ?

Comment: Here are instructions on how to configure FusionAuth to use an RSA key to sign tokens: https://fusionauth.io/blog/2020/05/06/securing-asp-netcore-razor-pages-app-with-oauth/ (look for "Next, go to the “JWT” tab"

Comment: Sure looks like AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi is focused only on Azure AD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#microsoftidentityweb I didn't see any reference to OIDC or other standards. You could use https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore as illustrated here: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-example-asp-netcore5

Comment: hmm yes, is what i ended to do , but i had a doubt ...